# Accessing a directory with a space in the directory name in Terminal using Python

Tags: python, working-directory

Hi I'm trying to write a script that takes a directory as an input from terminal

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
import os
# -- Change working directory.
def newWorkingDirectory():
    wd = os.getcwd()
    print('Current working directory is:', wd)
    print('Enter directory path.')
    folderPath = input()
    os.chdir(os.path.abspath(folderPath))
    wd = os.getcwd()
    print('Current working directory is:', wd)


newWorkingDirectory()
```

the code is working just fine if the directory name doesn't have spaces in it.
but if there is a space in the directory i get this error in **Terminal**:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "./workingDirectory.py", line 15, in <module>
        newWorkingDirectory()
 File "./workingDirectory.py", line 10, in newWorkingDirectory
        os.chdir(os.path.abspath(folderPath))
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/ali/asd\\ copy\\ 4'
```

The commands i'm using is:
**chmod +x WorkingDirectory** before i run the script for the first time.
and **./WorkingDirectory.py**

Thanks

Comment: The problem isn't the spaces in the path, the problem is that you're trying to escape the spaces with backslashes for no reason. Try inputting "asd copy 4" instead of "asd\ copy\ 4".

Comment: You are confusing data entered as standard input with data passed as parameters.  The second is subject to *shell expansion* where you would need quotes or backslashes - they are removed by the shell before being passed into the program.  Data entered via `input()` is not expanded by the shell, it goes straight into python, so quotes and backslashes are not removed.

Comment: Thank you. I get it now. Actually what I was doing is dragging the folder into the terminal so the escaping was automatically added.